# Can 1 be expressed with only irrationals in a non-trivial way?

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

There is an equation which I found interesting:

$$1=\phi+\frac{e^{i\pi}}{\phi}$$

where $\phi$ is the golden ratio (either its positive or negative value). Are there other ways to express 1 with only non-rational numbers, besides the obvious examples like $\pi / \pi$ or ${}-e^{i\pi}$?

Comment: @ZacWickstorm 1 = phi - 1/phi

Comment: The only reason this looks interesting is because we've replaced $-1$ with $e^{i\pi}$.

Comment: Sure, but can that be leveraged in another way to equate to 1?

Comment: $$1 = a^3 + a^2 + a,$$
where $a$ is a root of $x^3+x^2+x=1$. Or
$$1 = b^4 + b^3 + b^2 + b,$$
where $b$ is a root of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x=1$. Or ...

Comment: @Théophile Thank you, this is the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: So, if we take that concept to its logical extreme:

x=1; a=1,

$x^{2}$ + x = 1; a=$(-\phi, \frac{1}{\phi})$,

$x^{3}$ + $x^{2}$ + x; a=0.54369...,

...,

$x^{\infty}$ + ... + x = 1; a=(-1, $\frac{1}{2}$),

Does this pertain to any other areas in mathematics?

Comment: Here's an even simpler example: $1 = a+b$, where $a$ is any irrational number (so $b = 1-a$ is necessarily irrational also).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\phi$ can be *defined* as the (non-negative) solution to the equation

$$\phi^2 - \phi - 1 =0 \,.$$

Using this relationship, the equation you gave above basically is the same as $1 = -e^{i \pi}$. (Make the substitution for $1$, divide by $\phi$, rearrange terms...)

Consequently I don't understand why you consider one of those two equations to be "obvious" but do not also consider the other "obvious".

In any case, although $1 = -e^{i \pi}$ is well-known, I personally would not at all consider it "obvious". Ultimately all of this comes down to a matter of opinion it seems.

Anyway you could repeat the procedure used above with $\phi$ with many other irrational numbers, combine them with the $1 = -e^{i\pi}$ formula, and get similarly non-obvious relationships.